Agricultural Innovations of Pachyderms: High-Calorie Food
This is a question that has been driving me nuts for a couple of days.
I've developed a race of elephant-centaurs (imagine humanoid elephants with the body of an elephant where their legs should be). They are 8 metres tall from head to toes and, by my estimates, need to consume around 56000 kilocalories each day. They're also a largely agricultural society, and have managed to domesticate a large number of crops while artificially selecting for desired traits (i.e. bigger fruits, bigger leaves, etc.)
The problem is, I'm struggling to figure out the logistics of this. And I am aware that this is a VERY complex topic, so I'll just stick to one question at a time. Right now, I'm trying to figure out what their domesticated crops would BE like. As of now, they're confined to an area comprised mostly of temperate deciduous forests, tropical seasonal forests, and savannas, with an average temperature of 22°C and 800 mm worth of yearly precipitations on average.
So essentially, what crops could be harvested in this environment? And how many calories could each individual fruit/root/tuber realistically hold?

Note that an ordinary elephant needs about 70,000 kcal per day. And elephants somehow manage to find enough food without practicing agriculture... Oh, and bigger fruits and bigger leaves are nice to have, but what really counts is calories per hectare; for example, wheat averages some 14.4 million kcal per hectare, up to 57 million kcal per hectare with top-level modern technology.

@AlexP ...ok so I actually based myself on another post to calculate the caloric intake. Which means I need to reconsider MANY of my notes. And now I need to re-calculate these guys' daily caloric intake. (They weigh around 5.7 metric tons).
Additionally, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve here - more calories per square kilometre, but they really only have like... Iron Age-ish technology.

@AlexP
...actually, don't you mean 70,000 calories, instead of kilocalories?

(1) Food calories are kilocalories, sometimes called big calories, symbol kcal or Cal. The amount of energy needed to raise the temperature of 1 kg of water by 1 degree centigrade. (2) Roman wheat productivity varied between about 1 t/ha (Italy) and 2 t/ha (Egypt). (3) 1 kg of wheat flour provides about 3,300 kcal.

@AlexP ...so you mean to tell me that 1 kcal does NOT equate to 1,000 cal?

Yes, 1 kcal = 1 Cal = 1,000 cal = 4,184 J. A human adult male needs about 2,500 kcal = 10,460 MJ = 2.9 kWh per day. Food energy content is usually measured in kcal. (Note that the only units in practical use are cal or gram-calorie and kcal or kilogram-calorie. Nobody uses milli- or mega- or whatever other prefix. When speaking of food we say calorie but mean kilogram-calorie.)

@AlexP I think you're mixing up some things. Kilogram is a compound of kilo (1000) and gram (a unit of weight) - so kcal is kilo-calories a unit of energy. (kilogram-calorie would be a mix of weight and energy). And yes colloquially many people say "this drink has 300 kalories" when they mean it has 300 kcal = 300 kilo-calories = 300,000 calories.

@Falco: This is what they are called by old people. I'm not advocating for the use of obsolete names. (Basically it's the same thing as with mole née gram-molecule, and kilomole. The ghost of the centimeter-gram-second system of units still haunts us.)

Assuming they're all Elephant when it comes to their dietary preferences they'll grow something similar to Oak and Hazel with a sideline in something like Bamboo and Willow. These species all grow well in the temperate zone (and can be set in plantations over the other existing biomes, much like we plant cereals over former forests and jungles) and the trees all Coppice and Pollard well. This means the Willow can be harvested at ground level every few years and regrow from the stump and the Oak and Hazel can be cut back to a trunk head six feet up, from which they will branch profusely, to allow easier access to their primary food product, nuts and acorns. Wild Elephants will eat whole trees trunk, branch, twig, and leaf so something like Willow and especially Bamboo that grows fast will be wanted for bulk cellulose and leafy material. The calorie density of fruiting bodies is always relatively high so nuts and acorns will be extremely valuable to them, Oak and Hazel can both be grown very intensively under the climatic conditions you've indicated creating huge calorie yields.
If they're wanting/willing to get into cereals then, given the climate, Maize, Millet and possibly Rice are probably your go to crops, Maize being by far the most productive. They'd almost certainly need to add Legumes to their cereals for protein, vitamins, and minerals.
Now the king of foods, in terms of per acre calorie yield, is Potatoes, they can yield in excess of 18 million Calories per acre. There are modern potato cultivars adapted to almost every climate on the planet so they can definitely be grown in the areas you've indicated.
As to the limits of yield, without an anthropocentric period to benchmark from (i.e. I have no idea what level of farming technology you want to look at) I would suggest looking at the yields of modern "Heirloom" varieties. That's probably as good as it gets from selective breeding without a modern theory of genetics etc...

The idea is... basically Iron Age levels of technology for farming, does that help?

@DuskForm Then definitely look at Heirloom yields.

I have my own websites to look at that I have found, but do you have any recommendation in terms of where to find those yields?

@DuskForm Not on more than a per plant basis which is not handy for working out large scale yields.

As another answer pointed out, by far the most efficient crop, that can pretty much cover 100% calorie and nutrient needs of your Elephantaurs, is the humble potato.
Even with primitive, Iron Age technology, the potato is still the most efficient soil-to-calorie converter than can be practically grown.
The runner up is corn, but only if grown in a 3 Sisters combo of Corn+Beans+ Squash. Not all climates are good for these, but in hot and humid places, the 3 Sisters narrowly beat potato for calorie-per-unit of-labor, and are more resistant to blights and pests.
You said your Pachyderms at are Iron Age level, how much do they know of crop rotation? Fertilizer? Tilling? An elephant sized sapient being can be extremely efficient at tilling and turning the soil, deforesting and crop transportation, so almost by definition they would be much better at agriculture than Iron Age humans.
Finally, since your Pachyderms are nearly elephants, nothing stopping them from eating grass and bamboo whole, and thus skipping agriculture when years are lean.
Probably the most efficient way for their Agriculture to work is for the forerunners of their farmers to graze the local woods/plains/savannah to the bare ground, then the tillers come in and work the soil and plant crops. A few years later, the patch of farmland is abandoned to be reclaimed by nature, only to be grazed on a few years later. Its basically the simplest 2 field system mixed with your typical elephant grazing patterns.
As an Iron Age society, the Pachyderms would likely look for calories whenever they can find them, not just from  farming. Humans are omnivores, while elephants are reluctant, but occasional meat-eaters. Thus, it is not beyond the realm of possibility that your Elephantaurs would also opportunistically hunt (likely during deforestation), fish, or even herd smaller herbivores for consumption. And there is also the untapped potential of the oceans: not just for fish, but for the spectacular tonnage of seaweed and algae that would be perfectly edible to an elephant-man, and pretty much grow for free.

...what do you MEAN elephants will eat meat?! Where did you find this piece of info?!

They've been observed to eat bird nests with birds and eggs in them. Specifically, they have been caught on camera eating weaver birds and their eggs. They also eat all the bugs that normally live on the plants they consume, but this is more likely accidental.

@DuskForm Yeah my wife is the biologist in the family, she was telling me the other day that there are serious calls at the moment for the term herbivore to be abandoned, in turns out there are really only obligate carnivores and omnivores because everything that primarily eats plants will also eat at least some meat under certain circumstances. Those do vary according to species but the answer to "how much meat does X species eat?" is never zero.

@Ash ...Do you have some sources on this? Because I'm WAY too curious now.

@DuskForm I dug this article from 2012 up and I'll talk to the missus tomorrow evening when I'm logged in, she's very much asleep at this stage. Apparently Koalas actually are strict herbivores.

@DuskForm and an article on those dear, gentle possums https://www.australiangeographic.com.au/topics/wildlife/2017/04/killer-possums/

@GoingDurden oh also. I figure I should ask, but how many years is a few years...?

@DuskForm, that vastly depends on the type of crops and soil, but assuming relatively good soil that was stripped completely barren, 3 years is minimum, 5 is better. I would assume a grassy steppe/pampa/or prairie will replenish itself faster, if not exactly to the same level of soil nutrients. IF the Elephantaurs know about full crop rotation, with nitrogen binding plants involved in it, it can be an endless 3-4 year cycle with no breaks for millennia. The thing is, full crop rotation was not known in human Iron Age, but it easily could be, even learned by sheer accident..

@DuskForm, I would assume koalas are "herbivores" because there is a near zero chance one would hunt down another animal or could find carrion often enough to matter.
